# Easy-Peasy access other models

Tags: javascript, reactjs, easy-peasy

I am using `easy-peasy` as the state manager of react application
In the `actionOn` I need to access state of another model, How can I access `todos.items` in the `notes.onAddNote` ?

```js
import { createStore, StoreProvider, action, actionOn } from 'easy-peasy';

const todos= {
  items: [],
  addTodo: action((state, text) => {
    state.items.push(text)
  })
};

const notes = {
  items: [],
  addNote: action((state, text) => {
      state.items.push(text)
  }),
  onAddNote: actionOn(
    (actions, storeActions) => storeActions.notes.addNote,
    (state, target) => {
        // HOW TO READ todos items
    }
  ),
};

const models = {
   todos,
   notes 
};

const store = createStore(models);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

making onAddNote a `thunkOn` instead of `actionOn`

Comment: What difference did that make? Afaik the parameters for the callbacks of `thunkOn` and `actionOn` are both the same

Comment: See https://easy-peasy.vercel.app/docs/api/listeners.html